# dbWriteTable function from DBI package changes character encoding

Tags: r, oracle, encoding, dbi, roracle

I have encountered a problem using dbWriteTable function from the DBI package (also part of the ROracle package).

I am trying to export a data.frame to the Oracle server, where the data.frame has a column with mixed encoding ("unknown" and "UTF-8"). If I export all rows to the Oracle server then characters with accent (so UTF-8 characters) become non-UTF-8 characters on the Oracle server, while if I export only those rows which have UTF-8 encoding, then the characters are displayed correctly on Oracle.

It seems to me that dbWriteTable function downgrades the encoding to the lowest level found in the column. Is it a bug in the dbWriteTable function or have I missed setting the encoding properly? Does anybody know a workaround for the problem?

The code by which you could reproduce the problem I am facing with:

```
# Library
library("ROracle")

# Parameters
oracle_username   <- "USER"
oracle_password   <- "PASSWORD"
oracle_table_name <- "PLEASE_GIVE_A_NAME"

# Oracle kapcsolat
connection_string <- "THIS_IS_COMPANY_SPECIFIC"
drv               <- DBI::dbDriver("Oracle")

# Setting up the connection
con <- DBI::dbConnect(drv, username = oracle_username, password = oracle_password, dbname = connection_string) 

# Table to be exported to Oracle
dt_example <- as.data.frame(STRING = c("Unknown Urszula", "UTF-8 Uránia"))

# Checking the encoding
Encoding(dt_example$STRING)

# Exporting all rows
DBI::dbExecute(con, paste("drop table", toupper(oracle_table_name)))
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, name = toupper(oracle_table_name), value = dt_example, overwrite = TRUE, append = FALSE)
# --> The result on the server is Unknown Urszula and UTF-8 Ur??nia

# Exporting only the row with UTF-8 encoding
DBI::dbExecute(con, paste("drop table", toupper(oracle_table_name)))
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, name = toupper(oracle_table_name), value = dt_example[2, ], overwrite = TRUE, append = FALSE)
# --> The result on the server is UTF-8 Uránia
```

I have the following system / environment:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-suse-linux-gnu       
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.0                         
year           2018                        
month          04                          
day            23                          
svn rev        74626                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
```

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

```
> Sys.getenv(c("LANG", "ORACLE_HOME"))
                               LANG                         ORACLE_HOME 
                      "en_US.UTF-8" "/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib"
```

The NLS_LANG parameter is set to AMERICAN_AMERICA.EE8ISO8859P2 on the operating system.

The Oracle server has the following NLS setup:

```
select * from V$NLS_PARAMETERS;

NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET    EE8ISO8859P2
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advanced!

Comment: When working with UTF-8 characters I would set NLS_LANG to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! To be honest I have doubts that this would solve the problem because if I export rows having at least one UTF-8 character in each row , - like `as.data.frame(STRING = c("UTF-8 Uránia"))` - the results is fine on Oracle. It suggests me that Oracle is able to recognize the UTF-8 characters correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem: a data.frame with spanish letters like the `ñ` character. When I used `dbWriteTable` and `ROracle` to create a table the encoding of this characters was not correct.

If I use `Encoding(myData[[col]]) <- "UTF-8"` looks fine in R, but wrong in Oracle, so I transfromed the character data.frame columns to `local` and then to `latin1` and now looks ok in Oracle.

```
for (col in colnames(myData)){
    if (class(myData[[col]]) == "numeric"){
        next()
    } else {
        Encoding(myData[[col]]) <- "UTF-8"
        myData[[col]] <- enc2native(myData[[col]])}
        Encoding(myData[[col]]) <- "latin1"
}
```

For context... My Oracle db encoding is:
`SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;`
`NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8ISO8859P1`

And I have a `.Renviron` with this entry:
`NLS_LANG=".WE8ISO8859P1"`
So, when I use `dbGetQuery` I get the correct characters.